# Is there a version of sscanf() that doesn't start from the first byte?

Tags: c

In C, `fscanf()` doesn't necessarily read a file from its first byte; It reads the file from its current *access position*. I need a version of `sscanf()` that does the same with strings. Is there any function (standard or non-standard) for this purpose?

Update: It seems that I haven't asked the question quite well. I don't know the numeric value of the place/offset where this kind of `sscanf()` should start reading from; I want it to read from where the previous call to it finished. Thanks.

Comment: Simply `sscanf(string + n, ...)` instead of `sscanf(string, ...)`, where `n` is the desired start position.

Comment: I don't have `n`, @MichaelWalz. I want the new call to sscanf() start from where the previous call finished.

Comment: So why didn't you ask for this in your question ?

Comment: Remember that  `n <= strlen(string)` in the above [good comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273149/is-there-a-version-of-sscanf-that-doesnt-start-from-the-first-byte#comment69747781_41273149) must be true

Comment: @Arham - what do you have so far.  Please add some code or examples of what you are trying to parse.  It'll make the question easier to answer and allow others to come up with possibly better options.  scanf is not always the best approach.

Comment: oops yes, I was confused. `%n` is the way to go... [deleted comment]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In simple cases, you can use the `"%n"` specifier for that, like this

```
int x, y, length;
if (sscanf(string, "%d%d%n", &x, &y, &length) == 2) ...
```

Now `length` will have the "*position*" into the string so you can continue from there the next time

```
if (sscanf(string + length, "%d%d%n", &x, &y, &length) == 2) ...
```

In more complex cases you might need more than just `sscanf()`, or depending on the platform you are on you have [fmemopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) so you can use `fscanf()` while having a string like you wish and interact with it as if it was a file.

Comment: Consider `if (sscanf(string, "%d%dXYZ%n", &x, &y, &length) == 2)`.  This approach does not work as `length` may not be set.

Comment: @chux If the conversions don't all succeed, it probably doesn't make sense to continue where you left off, so it's a moot point.

Comment: @barmar The 2 conversions can succeed with `if (sscanf("123 456", "%d%dXYZ%n", &x, &y, &length) == 2)`, yet `length` is not changed and subsequent use can lead to UB.  Testing the return value of `sscanf()` is not sufficient nor moot when the scan needs to match text after specifiers.  Initializing the `length` and testing if it changed is sufficient for `sscanf()`.

Comment: @chux Doesn't the return value include the `%n` variable? So if everything succeeds, it should return `3`, not `2`.

Comment: @Barmar No.  With `sscanf("123 456", "%d%dXYZ%n"..` and `sscanf("123 456XYZ", "%d%dXYZ%n"...` both return 2. The first does not change `length`.  The 2nd does.   "Execution of a `%n` directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the `fscanf` function." 11 §7.21.6.2 12 which applies to `sscanf()`.  Hence the need to initialize and check if `length` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any function (standard or non-standard) for this purpose?

No, there isn't. You'll have to track how much to offset from your string and use it when calling `sscanf`.

```
sscanf(string + offset, ...);
```

To keep track of the offset, you can use the `%n` format specifier to let `sscanf` tell you how many characters it consumed.

```
int offset = 0;
int n = 0;
sscanf(string + offset, "....%n", ... &n);
offset += n;

...

sscanf(string + offset, "....%n", ... &n);
offset += n;
```

Answer (score 0):

C strings don't have a concept of current access position, except as you provide externally.  There cannot, therefore, be any variant of `sscanf()` that takes an inherent current access position into account.  In principle, there could be a variant that accepts a starting position as an additional argument, but that would be superfluous because, as @MichaelWalz observes, you can use routine pointer arithmetic to do that with `sscanf()` itself.

Comment: A variant of `sscanf()` could have an internal static variable, similar to the way `strtok()` works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `"%n` is the usual way to handle scanning a string from where a previous partial scan finished as `"%n"` records the offset of the scanning up to that point.

Append that to the end of the format and test if the index value changed from -1.  This works for simple and complex formats.

```
int scanf_buffer_2_step(const char * buffer) {
  int i;
  double d;

  // Initialize to a value that a successful scan would never use.
  int n = -1;

  // append                vv       vv
  sscanf(buffer, "Index:%d,%n", &i, &n);

  // Test for success
  if (n < 0) return 1; // fail

  // Advance pointer to next string position
  buffer += n; 

  // Do it some more    
  n = -1;
  sscanf(buffer, " Data:%lf End of the line %n", &d, &n);
  if (n < 0) return 1; // fail
  buffer += n; // Advance pointer to next string position

  if (buffer[0] != '\0') return 1; // fail (extra data)

  printf("(%i %f)", i, d);
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", scanf_buffer_2_step("Index:1, Data:123.456 End of the line"));
  printf("%d\n", scanf_buffer_2_step("Index:1, Data:123.456 End of the line extra"));
  printf("%d\n", scanf_buffer_2_step("Index:1,"));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
(1 123.456000)0
1
1
```

---

For the final scanning, consider appending `" %n"` if white-space, like a `'\n'` is allowed at the end of the string.

For `fscanf()`, additionally issues occur like checking the return value for `EOF`.